# R: Confused about factor levels and values (mtcars dataset)?

Tags: r

When I convert "am" into factors, I see that it correctly converts to two levels "0" and "1", but the values are 2 and 1, instead. How can I get them to be 0 / 1 as in the original data?

```
data(mtcars)
str(mtcars$am)
# num [1:32] 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...

 mtcars$am <- factor(mtcars$am)
 str(mtcars$am)
# Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 2 2 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
```

The consequence is, when I regress and plot with the abline, I get the wrong plot (treating 1 and 2 as the X values, instead of 0 and 1):

```
fit <- lm(mpg ~ am, mtcars)
qplot(am, mpg, data = mtcars) + geom_abline(intercept = fit$coef[1], slope = fit$coef[2])
fit
#----
Call:
lm(formula = mpg ~ am, data = mtcars)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)          am1  
     17.147        7.245
```

Comment: I'm getting `0` and `1` as x values.

Comment: In R the indices into factor levels are 1-based rather than 0-based.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, I'll show you two equivalent methods to prove they are equivalent:

```
qplot(am, mpg, data = mtcars) +
    #Method 1 
    geom_abline(intercept = fit$coef[1] - fit$coef[2], slope = fit$coef[2]) +
    #Method 2
    geom_smooth(method = "lm",se = FALSE,aes(group = 1))
```

There's nothing wrong with the factor encoding, you just have to adjust for the plotting coordinates (or just use `geom_smooth`).